# Write a function swap_halves(s) that takes a string s, and returns a new string in which the two halves of the string have been swapped

Tags: python, swap

Write a function `swap_halves(s)` that takes a string `s`, and returns a new string in which the two
halves of the string have been swapped.
For example, `swap_halves("good day sunshine")` would return `'sunshine good day'`.
I tried something like

```
def swap_halves (s):
    '''Returns a new string in which the two halves of the spring have swapped'''

    return (s[0:len(s)] + s[len(s):]  )
```

not sure how to do it without using `if` or other statements.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? How do you determine where to split the string?

Comment: I am sorry that what I wrote sounds confusing... this is what exactly my professor asked me to do for classwork, so the thing is we recently learned about strings and we have to use def function to manipulate string for example:

Comment: Write a function triple_outsides(s) that takes a string s, and returns a version of that string with only the first 3 characters from the beginning and end of the string tripled, and the rest of the
characters in the middle.
For example, triple_outsides("cayenne") would return 'cccayenneee'.                             return s[:1]*3 + s[1:-1] + s[-1]*3

Comment: in my case I have to write def formula which would change 2 strings position for example (good day sunshine) would give sunshine good day or (I love python) would give python I love

Comment: Your question and explanation are not consistent. In one of your comments(which I read first) was completely different than your actual post.

Comment: THANKS EVERYONE. Highly appreaciate your time and effort

Comment: Please don't edit your question to replace it with something completely different: it invalidates existing answers and comments. I've rolled back the last edit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly you want but this might work

```
def swap_halves (s):
  '''Returns a new string in which the two halves of the spring have swapped'''
  i = int(len(s)/2)
  print(s[i:] + s[:i]  )
swap_halves("good day sunshine ")
```

Comment: `swap_halves('good day bad sunshine')` output `ad sunshinegood day b`

Comment: it actually worked, i did return s[len(s)//2:] + s[:len(s)//2]

Answer (score 1):

```
def func(s):
    return(s[0:1]*3+s[1:]+s[-1:]*3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to `.split()` the text unless you don't mind some words getting cut say if your middle index falls in a word as someone pointed out, for string `good day bad sunshine` you wouldn't want `ad sunshinegood day b`

```
def swapper(some_string):
    words = some_string.split()
    mid = int(len(words)/2)
    new = words[mid:] + words[:mid]
    return ' '.join(new)

print(swapper('good day bad sunshine'))
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 images.py
> bad sunshine good day
> ```

As requested :

```
def tripler(text):
    new = text[:1] * 3 + text[1:-1] + text[-1:] * 3
    return new

print(tripler('cayenne'))
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 images.py
> cccayenneee
> ```

Comment: I am sorry that what i wrote sounds confusing... this is what exactly my professor asked me to do for classwork, so the thing is we recently learned about strings and we have to use def function to manipulate string for example:                               
Write a function triple_outsides(s) that takes a string s, and returns a version of that string with only the first 3 characters from the beginning and end of the string tripled, and the rest of the
characters in the middle.
For example, triple_outsides("cayenne") would return 'cccayenneee'.

Comment: so you actually want a completely different function then the one you described and showed you attempted?